# useEffect not getting called on local storage dependency

Tags: react-hooks, local-storage, use-effect

I tried as following but on change of localstorage useEffect is not getting called.
I have also tried adding dependency localStorage.getItem('quantity') but doesn't work.

```
import React from 'react';
import Categories from '../molecules/Categories';
import './SideBar.scss';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const SideBar = () => {

  let [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('quantity')));

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("in useEffect");
    const onStorage = () => {
      setQuantity(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('quantity')));
    };

    window.addEventListener('storage', onStorage);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('storage', onStorage);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='sidebar'>
      <Categories />
      <div>count:{quantity}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SideBar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Having an empty dependency array (as in your code above) will ensure that a `useEffect` runs only once, but I'm not sure why you would need this `useEffect` to run whenever storage is updated. This `useEffect` basically just adds an event listener, which does not need to be renewed after every storage update.

It looks like `onStorage` is what you actually want to run whenever storage is updated, but that is handled by the event listener that the `useEffect` adds. If you add a `console.log` inside `onStorage`, you should see that `onStorage` is running after every storage update.

Note, too, though, that a storage event will fire only if `localStorage` is updated by a different window/page; see this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event). If the same window is updating `localStorage`, then to trigger your event handler you will need to dispatch a storage event manually whenever you update the `quantity` in `localStorage`:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('storage'));
```

Comment: Hey first thanks for the suggestion but I tried that too and I'm getting nothing in console

Comment: Does the initial `console.log` in the `useEffect` run at least once? You also might throw a `console.log` in the returned callback to see if your event listener is being removed. (If your `SideBar` component is getting unmounted, that would trigger the callback and remove the event listener.)

Comment: Hey yeah initially useEffect is running once but it is not going into return part where event listener is removed, what might be the reason?

Comment: The storage event only fires if localStorage is updated by a different window; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event. See if you can solve the problem by manually dispatching a storage event whenever you update the quantity in localStorage: `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('storage'));`

Comment: Thankyou very much it is working now